# mySQL: editing/saving my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I have found the sample configuration  files provided with `mysql 5.0`, but I am not able to save them, when I edit them. I also tried saving using a different file name but I received an error by `windows` saying that I don't have permission to save file in that location (`I am an administrator`).

I need to edit the configuration file so I am able to save more data. I really can't figure out how to do it and have been struck on this problem since hours. anyone who can figure out whats going on?

Comment: ensure that your directory is not write protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to edit `my.cnf` file in linux opensuse 11.3
first of all open terminal window in su mode
then go to the directory /etc
then open `my.cnf` file in any of the text editor(kwrite);
now just insert the following two parameters after the line [mysqld]

```
wait_timeout=50
interactive_timeout=50
```

save and exit;
restart mysql;
now u can set your session time out by using the following:

```
set wait_timeout=5000;<br>
```

it is persistent

Answer (score 0):

You need to have root permissions on my.cnf file to edit it.

So login using root user and then you will be able to edit my.cnf and then you need to restart MySQL server in order to reflect changes.

Comment: do you mean that i should open mysql command line and then login and then edit configuration file?

Comment: yes you can login to server using root user and then edit using vim /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

I see that the basic information was included in directing someone to edit the my.cnf; however, there is no step by step available for beginners. I have a great article with step by step instructions and graphics that explains how to get the MySQL settings and how to change the my.cnf as root through shell. Hope the article helps.

[How to edit the MySQL my.cnf file](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/general-server-setup/edit-mysql-my-cnf)

Regards,
James R