# MySQL error - Access completely denied for all users on Fedora 26

Tags: mysql, fedora

I wanted to create a little authentication system using python/flask on linux (Fedora).

I chose MySQL as the main database, created a user table then quit with `exit`.

Then when I run my program I get this error :

> OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

So I tried to access to the database and try to fix it but I just can't get access to MySQL.

I tried all the commands and all the solutions that I found on many web pages(including those that are here) and nothing seem to work. Whether it's `mysql -u root -p` or `sudo mysql...` or even `mysqladmin`, I just get the same error over and over again.

> OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

A lot of the solutions that were provided were for Ubuntu, using even commands like `dpkg reconfigure` and stuff like that which doesn't work for me.

I don't even have the permission to write in /etc/my.cnf.

Here is my code in case you need it (in `views.py`):

```
from app import mysql
@app.route("/Authenticate")
def Authenticate():
    username = request.args.get('UserName')
    password = request.args.get('Password')
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from User where Username='" + username + "' and         Password='" + password + "'")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        return "Username or Password is wrong"
    else:
        return "Logged in successfully"
```

And (in `__init__.py`):

```
mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'EmpData'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

Comment: please visit here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: This is why I wrote "I don't even have the permission to write in /etc/my.cnf." Already did.

Comment: there is no other way in my knowledge.

Comment: I found a way to modify it thanks to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632733/mysql-editing-saving-my-cnf-file, but I can't start or restart mysql. When I use `service mysql start` I get this error > Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found. Same thing happens with `stop` and `restart`.